# Displaying images in tikz on a beamer, while holding some back to the next slide, unwanted copies

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, diagrams

It was rather complex to give a short description of my issue. Sorry for that. I am currently making a presentation. In this presentation I make use of the tikz package, and within the tikz picture I include some images that I obtain from my folder. It seems that, as long as we are not on the slide yet where they should be displayed, latex decides to display them at the top, which is not what I want!

My code is rather long:

```
\begin{figure}\[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\[every text node part/.style={align=left}, remember picture\]
    % Band
    \node at (0.5,0.5) {};
    \draw (3.75,0) -- (3.75,-6.5);
    \draw\[dashed\] (3.25,0) -- (3.25,-0.5);
    \draw\[dashed\] (2.75,-0.5) -- (3.25,-0.5);
    \draw\[dashed\] (2.75,-1.5) -- (3.25, -1.5);
    \draw\[dashed\] (3.25,-1.5) -- (3.25,-2);

    \draw\[dashed\] (2.75,-2) -- (3.25, -2);
    \draw\[dashed\] (2.75,-3) -- (3.25, -3);
    \draw\[dashed\] (3.25,-3) -- (3.25,-3.5);

    \draw\[dashed\] (2.75,-3.5) -- (3.25, -3.5);
    \draw\[dashed\] (2.75,-4.5) -- (3.25, -4.5);    
    \draw\[dashed\] (3.25,-4.5) -- (3.25,-5);

    \draw\[dashed\] (2.75,-5) -- (3.25,-5);
    \draw\[dashed\] (2.75,-6) -- (3.25,-6);
    \draw\[dashed\] (3.25,-6) -- (3.25,-6.5);

    % Box 1
    \draw (0,-0.5) -- (2.75,-0.5);
    \draw (0,-0.5) -- (0,-1.5); 
    \draw (0,-1.5) -- (2.75,-1.5);

    % Box 2
    \draw (0,-2) -- (2.75,-2);
    \draw (0,-2) -- (0,-3);
    \draw (0,-3) -- (2.75,-3);

    % Box 3
    \draw (0, -3.5) -- (2.75,-3.5);
    \draw (0, -3.5) -- (0, -4.5);
    \draw (0, -4.5) -- (2.75, -4.5);

    % Box 4
    \draw (0, -5) -- (2.75,-5);
    \draw (0, -5) -- (0,-6);
    \draw (0, -6) -- (2.75,-6);

    % Labels
    \node\[text centered\] at (-1,-0.75) {Uitgang 1};
    \node\[text centered\] at (-1,-1.25) {1,5,9,13};
    \node\[text centered\] at (-1,-2.25) {Uitgang 2};
    \node\[text centered\] at (-1,-2.76) {2,6,10,14};
    \node\[text centered\] at (-1,-3.75) {Uitgang 3};
    \node\[text centered\] at (-1,-4.25) {3,7,11,15};
    \node\[text centered\] at (-1,-5.25) {Uitgang 4};
    \node\[text centered\] at (-1,-5.75) {4,8,12,16};


    \only<1>
    {\node at (5.5, 0.0) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.05) {16};

     \node at (5.5, -0.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.8) {3};

     \node at (5.5, -1.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -1.55) {10};

     \node at (5.5, -2.25) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -2.3) {5};

     \node at (5.5, -3) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -3.05) {1};

     \node at (5.5, -3.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -3.8) {12};

     \node at (5.5, -4.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -4.55) {14};

     \node at (5.5, -5.25) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -5.3) {11};}

    \only<2-> \node at (0.5, -5.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};  
    \only<2-> \node at (0.6, -5.6) {16};
    \only<2>
    {\node at (5.5, 0) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.05) {3};

     \node at (5.5, -0.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.8) {10};

     \node at (5.5, -1.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -1.55) {5};

     \node at (5.5, -2.25) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -2.3) {1};

     \node at (5.5, -3) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -3.05) {12};

     \node at (5.5, -3.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -3.8) {14};

     \node at (5.5, -4.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -4.55) {11};}   

     \only<3-> \node at (0.5, -4) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};   
     \only<3-> \node at (0.55, -4.1) {3};
     \only<3>
    {\node at (5.5, 0) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.05) {10};

     \node at (5.5, -0.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.8) {5};

     \node at (5.5, -1.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -1.55) {1};

     \node at (5.5, -2.25) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -2.3) {12};

     \node at (5.5, -3) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -3.05) {14};

     \node at (5.5, -3.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -3.8) {11};}    

     \only<4-> \node at (0.5, -2.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}}; 
     \only<4-> \node at (0.55, -2.6) {10};
     \only<4>
    {\node at (5.5, 0) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.05) {5};

     \node at (5.5, -0.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.8) {1};

     \node at (5.5, -1.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -1.55) {12};

     \node at (5.5, -2.25) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -2.3) {11};

     \node at (5.5, -3) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -3.05) {14};}

     \only<5-> \node at (0.5, -1) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};   
     \only<5-> \node at (0.6, -1.1) {5};
     \only<5>
    {\node at (5.5, 0) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.05) {1};

     \node at (5.5, -0.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.8) {12};

     \node at (5.5, -1.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -1.55) {11};

     \node at (5.5, -2.25) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -2.3) {14};}

     \only<6-> \node at (1.5, -1) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};   
     \only<6-> \node at (1.6, -1.1) {1};
     \only<6>
    {\node at (5.5, 0) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.05) {12};

     \node at (5.5, -0.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.8) {11};

     \node at (5.5, -1.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -1.55) {14};}

     \only<7-> \node at (1.5, -5.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}}; 
     \only<7-> \node at (1.6, -5.6) {12};
     \only<7>
    {\node at (5.5, 0) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.05) {11};

     \node at (5.5, -0.75) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.8) {14};}

     \only<8-> \node at (1.5, -4) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};   
     \only<8-> \node at (1.6, -4.1) {11};
     \only<8>
    {\node at (5.5, 0) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}};
     \node at (5.5, -0.05) {14};}

     \only<9-> \node at (1.5, -2.5) {\includegraphics\[width=0.8cm\]{envelop.png}}; 
     \only<9-> \node at (1.6, -2.6) {14};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}][1]][1]
```

It creates nine slides in total. On each slide, one of the envelopes showed on the right is assigned to an exit on the left. Start slide:
[image]

First iteration:
[image]

Next iteration:
[image]

As you could imagine, the envelopes on the top are unwanted. Does anyone konw how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please give us a compilable example of your code. And try to minimize as much as possible. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that something broke when inserting your code into the question and many disturbing `/` where added. Can you try again?

Comment: Please make your code in to a document that can be compiled is in [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Currently you do not show how you set-up beamer.